# how to edit views.py in django when installed in ubuntu server

Tags: django, ubuntu

I installed Django in ubuntu server ,when I connect t my public server:8080 I got Django installed, now how to edit urls.py file or  tests.py  in server, should I use WinSCP or is there any graphical option to edit files in server to modify Django website

Answer (score 0):

As a full Linux platform you can use any of these https://www.inmotionhosting.com/blog/ubuntu-text-editors/
I use Nano which can be run from within the folder of the file in question from the command line using

```
nano views.py
```

Assuming you're running the CLI version I suggest you edit your files from outside the Ubuntu non-graphical server and then upload those files with your preferred FTP platform afterwards.

[This link also discusses the different types of editors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615178/getting-the-default-text-editor-used-in-system) 
as well as how to find yours using `$ echo $EDITOR`